# TypeError: property Array.prototype.splice.call(...) is non-configurable and can't be deleted

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

When I attempt to load my page in FF I get this error:

```
TypeError: property Array.prototype.splice.call(...) is non-configurable and can't be deleted
```

Here is the prototype

```
   HTMLElement.prototype.selectorAll = function (selectors, fun) {

        var sels = Array.prototype.splice.call(this.querySelectorAll(selectors), 0)
        if (!fun) { return sels; }; fun.call(sels);
    };
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) rather than [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to just create a new `Array` from the original collection.

```
var sels = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.querySelectorAll(selectors), 0)
```

The error is because `splice` is also attempting to modify the original collection:

```
var a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

a.slice(0);
console.log(a); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

a.splice(0);
console.log(a); // []
```

And the `NodeList` returned from `querySelectorAll()` has a non-configurable property that `splice` can't alter as it expects.